# How to delete json files in a folder using php

Tags: php

I need to delete only json files which existing in a particular folder using php. am trying this code

```
$path = "uploads/File Name/";
$files = scandir($path);
foreach ($files as $csv_file) {
  $filepath = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $csv_file);
  echo $filepath . '<br/>';
  unlink($csv_file);
}
```

but when am using this its deleting all the file. I need to delete only json files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = "uploads/File Name/";
$files = glob("$path/*.json");
foreach ($files as $csv_file) {
$filepath = str_replace(" ", "\ ", $csv_file);
echo $filepath . '<br/>';
unlink($csv_file);
```

}

You can try this code.